# What is the difference between the standard library and the standard template library?

Tags: c++, stl, std

I keep seeing reference to both the C++ standard Library and the C++ Standard Template Library (STL). What is the difference between them? Wikipedia mentions that they share some headers but that's about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info. First time I've seen a question that's a dupe of a *tag* ;-)

Comment: who'd have thunk it, editing the tag wiki was worth it after all :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [*Standard Template Library*](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) (STL) is a library of containers, iterators, algorithms, and function objects, that was created by Alexander Stepanov; the SGI website has the canonical implementation and documentation.

The *standard library* is the library that is part of C++; it includes most of the Standard Template Library (STL).

In common usage, "STL" is also used to refer to the parts of the C++ standard library that come from or are derived from the actual SGI STL.  For example, people often use "STL" to refer to `std::vector` and the rest of the containers in the C++ standard library, since they originated in the SGI STL.

Comment: I always believed that STL was created by Alexander Stepanov while working at HP ...

Comment: Yeah, it was developed by Stepanov, and Wiki agrees on the HP thing. I don't suppose anyone knows how it ended up with SGI then?

Comment: @jalf:  [Stepanov's website](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/) indicates the SGI implementation was completed by "Matt Austern with Hans Boehm (managed by Alexander Stepanov)."  Beyond that, I couldn't find any other information.

Comment: I dislike "includes". That implies that (a) the copy was verbatim [which it was not], and (b) that changes to one mean changes in the other [which they do not]. Working "based on" into the sentence is best.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: and (c) everything in one is in the other [which is not].

Comment: To add to the answer, what you're using now (with the `std::` prefix) is probably not "STL", but just "the standard library", unless you deliberately obtained and installed a copy of the historic STL.