# Time Complexity of std::multimap::equal_range

Tags: c++, stl, complexity-theory

Good afternoon, I am wondering what the time complexity of `std::multimap::equal_range` is? Is it Big-O(n) or BIG-0(log n). I remember reading that the time complexity of `std::multimap::erase` "is logarithmic plus linear time for the length of the sequence being removed." <http://frank.mtsu.edu/~csjudy/STL/Multimap.html>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++03 standard, Table 69 ("Associative container requirements") in 23.1.2 says that `equal_range` has logarithmic complexity.

Comment: Steve Jessop, Thank you for answer. I just accepted your answer, We are using a multimap container which has char * pointer as the key, We found that equal_range correctly as long as the char * pointers are not bad pointers(Windows term). In Linux, they refer to bad pointer as "Address out of range". Is our observation about equal_range's requirement for good char * pointers correct. We chose not not to std::string as a multimap key because the strcmp was so expensive compared to the good pointer comparer functor bool(char *left, char *right). Thank you.

Comment: As far as the standard is concerned yes, keys in a map have to remain valid values, and any use of a pointer to freed data, or a bad address, even just comparing it as a pointer value without dereferencing it, is technically invalid. In practice I'm a bit surprised that it actually failed - are you sure your code never dereferenced the pointers?

Comment: Steve Jessop, Thank you for your reply, If our code had actually deferenced a bad pointer, would it be correct to say that an access violation(Windows) or a bus error/segmentation fault would have happened on(Linux)? Here is a code excerpt: 1.UnmapViewOfFile(PrevMapPtr); 2. TmpPrevMapPtr = PrevMapPtr; 3. typedef std::multimap<char *,Range>::const_iterator I; std::pair<I,I> b = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr); 4. for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){ ranges_type.erase(i->second); } Thank you for your help.

Comment: Steve Jessop, Thank you for your reply, If our code had actually deferenced a bad pointer, would it be correct to say that an access violation(Windows) or a bus error/segmentation fault would have happened on(Linux)? Here is a code excerpt:     1.UnmapViewOfFile(PrevMapPtr);   2. TmpPrevMapPtr = PrevMapPtr;    3. typedef std::multimap<char *,Range>::const_iterator I;   4. std::pair<I,I> b = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr);   5. for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){ ranges_type.erase(i->second); }   6. erasecount = mmultimap.erase(TmpPrevMapPtr);   Thank you for your help.

Comment: Steve Jessop, I apologize for posting 2 versions of my comment. If you have the time, please look at the comment just preceding this one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frank: that code doesn't look to me as if it dereferences the pointers used as keys, but I don't see where the map is defined. Maybe you gave it a comparator that does dereference the pointers. And yes, access violation/segv errors indicate dereferencing a bad address of some kind or another.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, Thank you for your reply. Yesterday, in another thread on this same topic, you stated" unfortunately you would need to remove that key[char * pointer] from the multimap before you unmap your file. Or you could make a copy of the string from the mapped file, to insert into the map, but if you're going to do that you might as well use std::string. So I followed your recommendation and so far the code excerpt seems to be functioning.The multimap is defined as std::multimap<char *,Range> where Range is a class. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, Here is the class Range. Thank you. class Range { 
     public:   
  
   Range(int low, int high, char* ptr = 0,char* mapptr = 0, int stamp = 0){  // [low,high]
   mLow = low;
   mHigh = high;
   mPtr  = ptr;
   mMapPtr = mapptr;
              mStamp = stamp
   }

   bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const{
   return mHigh < rhs.mHigh;
   } 
) const { return mCaseNumber; }
     private:   
   int mLow;   
   int mHigh; 
   char* mPtr;
   char* mMapPtr;
   int mStamp;
}; // class Range

Answer (score 2):

`equal_range` is an O(log n) operation returning the pair of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

This means it will return an iterator range starting with the first key that is greater-than or equal-to the search key and ending with the first key that is greater than the search key.

Comment: @Cory Nelson, Thank you for answer. I just accepted your answer. Will std::multimap::equal_range work with search keys that are char* pointers? Do I have to find a good function for hashing pointer values? Thank you.

Comment: `equal_range` will work with any type.  It uses the comparer you give in the `multimap` constructor -- if the default one (`less<T>`) for `char*` doesn't do what you want, you'll need to define your own.  Either way, it doesn't need to do any hashing.

Comment: @Cory Nelson, I stepped through the multimap::equal_range function using a debugger and I found the default one less<T> for char* compares pointer addresses , Left_ < Right_. Is there a better comparer for char * pointer? Is so , what might it look like? If I understand your comment, I don't have to hash the char* pointer keys? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The comparer is a function type with signature `bool(T a, T b)`, returning `true` if `a` comes before `b`.  It can be a function pointer or a functor.

Comment: @Frank, I provided an appropriate compare function in answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982760/is-it-possible-for-stdmultimapequal-range-to-return-incorrect-results/5983011#5983011).

Comment: If you want to treat your char* as strings and order them that way (instead of memory addresses) you can supply a functor that uses strcmp (or use strcmp directly?). Or you can just use std::string instead of char*, whose std::less works the right way.

Comment: @Christian Rau, Thank you for your reply. The problem is we that we invalidate the char * pointer key using UnMapViewOfFile(TmpPrevMapPtr). Therefore the string is now a bad ptr so we can't use strcmp? What should we do? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: unfortunately you would need to remove that key from the multimap before you unmap your file. Or you could make a *copy* of the string from the mapped file, to insert into the map, but if you're going to do that you might as well use `std::string`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, Thank you for your help. If we use std::string, would the functor compare the std::string's? How expensive would the std::string conversion and comparsion be?

Comment: @Frank: I don't know the cost, measure it.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really found a better source for this sort of information than the [SGI STL Programmer's Guide](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/). In this case the page you're interested in is the Sorted Associative Container [concept page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/SortedAssociativeContainer.html) which states under the Complexity Guarantees section:

> Lower bound, upper bound, and equal range are logarithmic. [1]
>
> ...
>
> [1] This is a much stronger guarantee than the one provided by Associative Container. The guarantees in Associative Container only apply to average complexity; worst case complexity is allowed to be greater. Sorted Associative Container, however, provides an upper limit on worst case complexity.

Comment: @olivier Seiler, Thank you for your answer. I just accepted your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the standard is more authoritative, but the SGI docs are more convenient. Occasionally you'll be caught out by something that was changed between there and the C++ standard.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, if you're aware of any specific changes between SGI and the standard, could you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266386/what-are-the-specific-differences-between-the-original-stl-and-those-parts-of-it ? Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: I've starred it and I'll try to remember, but to be honest since I've installed Foxit, that can search PDFs in less than the geological time taken by Adobe Reader, I don't use the SGI docs very often any more :-)