# Is it possible for std::multimap::equal_range to return incorrect results?

Tags: c++, stl

Good afternoon,  I am finding that `std:multimap::equal_range` returns incorrect results sometimes. Is this possible? If so, is there a workaround or some error in my code or hash function for pointers. Thank you.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
typedef std::multimap<char *,Range>::const_iterator I;
std::pair<I,I> b = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr);
for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){
    ranges_type.erase(i->second);
}
erasecount = mmultimap.erase(TmpPrevMapPtr);
```

where mmultimap has a hashed pointer key and a Range value. The class Range looks like this:

```
class Range { 
public:   
    explicit Range(int item){// [item,item] 
      mLow = item;
      mHigh = item;
      mPtr  = 0;
      mMapPtr = 0;
      mStamp = 0;
    }

    Range(int low, int high, char* ptr = 0,char* mapptr, int stamp){  
      mLow = low;
      mHigh = high;
      mPtr  = ptr;
      mMapPtr = mapptr;
      mStamp = stamp;
    }        

    int low() const { return mLow; }   
    int high() const { return mHigh; }
    char* getPtr() const { return mPtr; }
    char* getMapPtr() const { return mMapPtr; }
    int getStamp() const { return mStamp; }

private:   
    int mLow;   
    int mHigh; 
    char* mPtr;
    char* mMapPtr;
    int mStamp;
}; // class Range
```

Comment: What is your `char*` key?  Is it a pointer to a C string or something else?  Do you actually mean to use a pointer here?  (That is, do you really want to identify elements by the address of particular instances of strings?)  Are you sure that you don't want to use `std::string` or some other string class?

Comment: @James McNellis, Thank you for your reply, You are correct that char * key is a pointer to a C string. Ideally , I would like like use a pointer to a C string. I remember taking a computer science class 5 years ago where the Professor Roni Khartoun gave us a assignment where we had to build a hash map with keys which were pointers to a C string, I did not use STL to solve that program. Are you saying in STL that is better not use char* pointers as keys to std::multimap? Thank you.

Comment: you can use `char*` as keys to `std::multimap`, as long as you use them correctly. Just realize that the comparison operators (in particular, `<` and `std::less`) show whether they point to identically the same string, not whether they point to strings with identical contents.

Comment: It's best to avoid C strings, period.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `char*` pointers for equality, when you want to compare C strings. You need to supply a comparison functor to multimap or (better yet) use std::string. Consider the following program and note how `A1` != `A2`, but `strcmp(A1, A2)==0`.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct compare {
 bool operator()(char *left, char *right) const {
  return std::strcmp(left,right) < 0;
 }
};


int main() {
  char A1[] = "A";
  char A2[] = "A";

  std::multimap<char*, int> bad;
  bad.insert(std::pair<char*,int>(A1, 1));
  bad.insert(std::pair<char*,int>(A2, 1));
  std::cout << bad.count("A") << ", " << bad.count(A1) << "\n";

  std::multimap<char*, int, compare> good;
  good.insert(std::pair<char*,int>(A1, 1));
  good.insert(std::pair<char*,int>(A2, 1));
  std::cout << good.count("A") << ", " << good.count(A1) << "\n";

  std::multimap<std::string, int> better;
  better.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>(A1, 1));
  better.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>(A2, 1));
  std::cout << better.count("A") << ", " << better.count(A1) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I left a line of code in my excerpt: UnmapViewOfFile(PrevMapPtr); TmpPrevMapPtr = PrevMapPtr;typedef std::multimap<char *,Range>::const_iterator I; std::pair<I,I> b = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr); for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){ ranges_type.erase(i->second); } erasecount = mmultimap.erase(TmpPrevMapPtr);

Comment: Thank you for reply. I left a line of code in my excerpt: 1. UnmapViewOfFile(PrevMapPtr); 2. TmpPrevMapPtr = PrevMapPtr;3. typedef std::multimap<char *,Range>::const_iterator I; 4. std::pair<I,I> b = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr); 5. for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){ ranges_type.erase(i->second); } 6. erasecount = mmultimap.erase(TmpPrevMapPtr); Since UnMapOfViewOfFile invalidates the char * pointer, we cannot use strcmp What should we do? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not certain what you are saying, and I don't know what `UnmapViewOfFile` does, but I can say this: the keys must be valid for the duration of their existence in the map. The best fix: use `std::string` as the key type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it out. UnMapViewOfFile "Unmaps a mapped view of a file from the calling process's address space". We are building a memory-mapped file view application. I think we defer the UnMapViewOfFile until after we have invoked std::multimap::equal_range. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using the iterators is wrong.  When using the erase method, the iterator became invalid. It must be reassigned with the erase method returned value.

In other words:

```
for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){
   ranges_type.erase(i->second);
}
```

should be

```
I i = b.first; 
while (i != b.second){
   i = ranges_type.erase(i->second);
}
```