# Double free or corruption with binary search tree object

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, binary-search-tree

I've tried to implement a function that builds a BST from the bottom up. It works by starting with an `std::vector` (call this `nodeList`) of `SPnodes` (my object that is equivalent to a node in a tree), doing a comparison between adjacent entries in the vector, and if the comparison yields true, it creates a new `SPnode` based on a criteria I've defined.

It then points `m_left` (left child) to one of the `SPnodes` in the comparison (which one is determined by another comparison function) and likewise, points `m_right` to the other `SPnode`.

It adds the newly created `SPnode` to a different `std::vector` (call this `parentList`), then repeats the process with the remaining `SPnodes` in `nodeList`.

The function is recursively called with `parentList` being passed as its argument. The `parentList` is then treated as the new `nodeList` and the steps are repeated until `nodeList` contains only a single `SPnode`.

**Problem**

My problem is that when I run it, I get a `double free or corruption` error. I'm still not completely clear on what is causing it. It seems like it has something to do with the `SPnode` objects in an `std::vector` and memory at a certain address being deallocated twice? I see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568072/should-i-always-call-vector-clear-at-the-end-of-the-function) answer that when the `std::vector` destructor is called, it in turn calls the destructor for all objects it contains. My `~SPnode` destructor frees memory by calling `delete` on `m_left` and `m_right`. So when `nodeList` goes out of scope, how is it possible that the memory is being deallocated twice?

Apart from my understanding of the issue, I've seen several solutions that say using a custom copy constructor and overloading the assignment operator are ways to get around the problem. However, in order to deepcopy a given `SPnode` would I not also have to recursively deepcopy all the child `SPnodes`? If so, how could I do this in a simple copy constructor?

My code for the function and `SPnode` class is below. Note that I realize I should have used smart pointers from the start, but I didn't realize until much later that they even existed and switching everything over would be a serious pain.

**Code**

`SPnode` header:

```
#ifndef SPNODEOBJ_H
#define SPNODEOBJ_H

#include "IntervalObjects.h"
#include "IntervalObj.h"
#include "InVecObj.h"
#include "StandardLib.h"

// --- SPnode Class ------------------------------------------------------------

// SPnode (or Subpaving Node), is a node in a binary tree which contains a
// parameter "box" which is an InVec object, and a left and right child which
// are also SPnode objects. These SPnode objects are the resultant boxes from 
// calling the expand method on m_box. This implementation allows for two 
// important characteristics: there is a way to determine "where" a given box in
// a subpaving is by iterating over a node's left or right child, which in turn
// allows for greater efficiency; secondly, the tree structure gives a "history"
// of the subpaving, which allows for the determination of parent boxes.
class SPnode
{
private:

    InVec m_box;

    // left and right children of this SPnode object - note that these must be
    // pointers in order to use them in the definition of the class, otherwise 
    // SPnode would reference itself in its definition
    SPnode* m_left;
    SPnode* m_right;

    // a boolean sepcifying whether the SPnode m_box is in the given subpaving 
    bool m_inSP;

    bool m_hasBeenIterated;

public:

    SPnode(InVec box): m_box(box), m_left(NULL), m_right(NULL), m_inSP(true), 
    m_hasBeenIterated(false) {}

    ~SPnode() {delete m_left; delete m_right;}


    // getters and setters
    InVec getBox() const {return m_box;}
    SPnode* getLeft() const {return m_left;}
    SPnode* getRight() const {return m_right;}
    bool getInSP() const {return m_inSP;}
    bool getIterated() const {return m_hasBeenIterated;}

    void setBox(const InVec box) {m_box = box;}
    void setLeft(SPnode* const p_node) {m_left = p_node;}
    void setRight(SPnode* const p_node) {m_right = p_node;}
    void setInSP(bool truth) {m_inSP = truth;} // when this is called truth 
                                               // should only be false
    void setIterated(bool truth) {m_hasBeenIterated = truth;}

    bool isLeaf() const;


    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const SPnode &ASP);




    friend void expand(SPnode &ASP);
    friend InVec lower(const InVec &box, const Interval &width, int axis);
    friend InVec upper(const InVec &box, const Interval &width, int axis);
    friend void mince(SPnode &ASP); 
    friend SPnode regularize(ImList &list, InVec box);
    friend SPnode* recRegularize(std::vector<InVec> &list, SPnode &parentNode);
};

#endif
```

and the function in question:

```
// This function builds up a tree from a list of user defined boxes
SPnode listToTree (std::vector<InVec> &boxList)
{

    std::vector<SPnode> nodeList;

    for (auto box : boxList)
    {
        nodeList.push_back(SPnode(box));
    }

    return recListToTree(nodeList);
}


SPnode recListToTree (std::vector<SPnode> &nodeList)
{

    std::cout << "nodelist size is: " << nodeList.size() << "\n";

    if (nodeList.size() == 1)
    {
        return nodeList.at(0);
    }


    std::vector<SPnode> parentNodeList;

    int counter = 0;

    for (auto node : nodeList)
    {
        if (node.getIterated())
        {
            counter += 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (counter + 1 == nodeList.size())
        {
            parentNodeList.push_back(SPnode(node.getBox()));
            break;
        }

        if (node.getBox().isAdjacent(nodeList.at(counter + 1).getBox()))
        {
            SPnode newNode
            (SPnode(node.getBox().combine(nodeList.at(counter + 1).getBox())));



            if (lessThan(node.getBox(), nodeList.at(counter + 1).getBox()))
            {
                newNode.setLeft(&node);
                newNode.setRight(&(nodeList.at(counter + 1)));
            }

            else
            {
                newNode.setRight(&node);
                newNode.setLeft(&(nodeList.at(counter + 1)));
            }

            parentNodeList.push_back(newNode);

            nodeList.at(counter).setIterated(true);
            nodeList.at(counter + 1).setIterated(true);

            counter += 1;
        }


        else
        {
            parentNodeList.push_back(SPnode(node.getBox()));

            nodeList.at(counter + 1).setIterated(true);

            counter += 1;
        }

    }

    recListToTree(parentNodeList);
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: looks like a rule of 5/3/0 violation.

Comment: Your implementation of `SPnode` violates [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: And you're storing pointers to automatic variables, for example `&node`. You can't use these for anything when that function returns and you're absolutely not allowed to `delete` them.

Comment: Your `SPnode` class must be able to *safely* copy and assign SPnode to another SPnode.  That's what is required for that type (and any type) to work with `std::vector` without UB or memory corruption issues.  Obviously, your SPnode fails this requirement.  The same with `InVec`.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of what the Rule of Three stated, thanks. So, in this example how would I manage to implement a copy constructor if each pointer is pointing to an object which points to more objects etc...?

Comment: `SPnode(const SPnode& rhs)` -- You need to implement this function.  This function creates a copy of a new `SPnode` from the existing `SPnode` (rhs).  How to do that?  Well, you have to traverse `rhs` and build the new SPnode from scratch so that both `rhs` and SPnode are functionally equivalent (same data, same structure, etc.).