# When will the data from a vector freed?

Tags: c++, vector, scope

I have the following code

```
void test(MyDataType * t)
{
   vector<MyDataType> tmp;
   tmp.push_back(MyDataType(2,24));
   t = tmp.data();
}

void test2()
{
    MyDataType * t;
    test(t);
    // Do some stuff with the data pointed by t
}
```

When will the data stored in the vector freed? It is out of scope after the `test` function call end. Is that correct?

Comment: `t` is by-value to `test`, so `t = ...` is pointless, and means nothing to the caller anyway. There is nothing "out of scope" in this code, since the value of `t` in `main` is as indeterminate *after* the call to `test` as it was before. An easier-to-understand example would be `MyDataType *test() { ... return tmp.data(); }`  and `t = test();` in `main()`. That's is also much clearer to see a genuine dangling pointer, which it certainly would be.

Comment: First of all your signature would have to be `void test(MyDataType*& t)` for this idea to work. But more importantly, yes the vector `tmp` falls out of scope and is destroyed at the end of `test` so `t` is now a dangling pointer that points to a destroyed obect

Comment: very related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568072/should-i-always-call-vector-clear-at-the-end-of-the-function

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/5980430 . Also note what @ WhozCraig said

Comment: It isnt nice at all to change the question substantially after you got answers. Please do not fix the question. Corrections go to answers not questions

Comment: look, both answers address the problem you wanted to ask for and the additional problem in your code that only slipped in by accident. By fixing the second in your question you invalidate both answers.

Comment: I switch back, but actually I wanted to ask what @CoryKramer wrote.

Comment: as I wrote, both answers do address this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When will the data stored in the vector freed? It is out of scope after the test function call end. Is that correct?

Yes correct.

If you would return the pointer from the function it would be a dangling pointer.

However, there is another subtle problem in your code: You pass the pointer `t` by value, hence the assignment inside test will have no effect on the `t` in `main`. If you use `t` in `main` you will probably get a segfault not because the vector is already out of scope, but because you never initialized the `t` in `main`.

Comment: *Probably* a segfault, but there are no guarantees with undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom thx, the point wasnt the segfault but the cause for whatever happens, fixed

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the destructor for the `vector` object `tmp` should free the storage. Your program exhibits undefined behavior, or at least it would if you passed the pointer out properly.