# What is the time complexity of std::deque::erase function?

Tags: c++, stl

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/erase/) it says the following about the time complexity:

> Linear on the number of elements erased (destructions). Plus, **depending on the particular library implemention**, up to an additional linear time on the number of elements between position and one of the ends of the deque.

From the first sentence I understand that if you want to erase any number in the deque, the worst case complexity will be O(1).

Now the second sentence makes me confused. What does depending on the particular library implementation mean? I'm using the STL library, the same library that comes with the GCC compiler. How can I learn the correct time complexity of this function in my case?

I need it to be O(1) because I'm running O(n) erase calls, if `std::deque::erase` is O(n) my algorithm will have a quadratic complexity which is something that I don't want.

Comment: What does "any number in the deque" mean?!

Comment: "The STL library" is a) not a thing, and b) not an *implementation*.

Comment: sorry, I meant any element inside the deque, in my case it's just an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to remove `n` items from your deque, you normally want to use the `remove/erase` idiom.

You start with `std::remove` to remove the `n` items themselves. That basically partitions your collection into two pieces: those at the beginning that you didn't remove, and some space at the end that contains things you don't care about any more.

It returns an iterator pointing to the boundary between those two. You can then erase from there to the end (once) to get rid of the items you don't care about any more.

`std::remove` basically does what I think of as a "ripple copy" -- it walks through the collection from beginning to end, and when it finds an item you want to remove, it finds the next item you want to keep, and copies it over the one you want to remove<sup>1</sup>.

If you don't need to maintain the order of the items you keep, you can often improve speed even more. Starting from the beginning of the collection, find an item you want to get rid of (i.e., one that you'd currently `erase`). Starting from the *end* find an item you want to keep (i.e., one you would *not* `erase`). Swap those two items, and continue the search "inward" until the two positions meet. Now all the items you want to erase are at the end of the collection. You can erase all of them in O(1).

In theory, the overall complexity for these two is the same--both are O(N). In many cases, however, copying an item is *relatively* expensive (vs. just determining whether to keep the item). This minimizes the number of items that get copied/moved, so when copy/moving is expensive it can save quite a bit of time (though, as already noted, it's not suitable if the order of the remaining objects matters).

---

1. Note that as of C++11, these can be moves instead of copies (e.g., if you supply move iterators).

Answer (score 0):

cplusplus.com covers the C++ standard library, not the original STL. The C++ stdlib subsumes [most of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064010/what-is-the-difference-between-the-standard-library-and-the-standard-template-li) the STL, and it has several implementations, which typically (if not always) derive from the STL code, but may change it in various ways. The GCC implementation is, in fact, the STL + GNU modifications. According to the standard, `erase` may be linear in the number of elements in the `deque`.

If you want to find out the complexity of this operation in your implementation, either read [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/) (though I can't find `deque` in there anywhere), read the source, or profile.